# How can I select a router that I want to connect on Android?

Tags: wi-fi, networking, router

In my residence, there's a network which has many different routers to provide Wi-Fi signals. One of these routers doesn't work properly. I can connect to this router, but it can't connect to the Internet through this router. Unfortunately, it has the strongest signal. So, I have to select another router manually. How can I do that?

I know how to connect to the Wi-Fi. My problem is that I have many routers which have the same SSID. But one of the routers which have the strongest signal does not work properly. So, I have to choose another router.

For example, one of the SmartCampus does not work.

[image]

Comment: Do all those networks share the same SSID (i.e. do they appear using the very same name), or can you tell them apart by the name displayed in your list of available WiFi networks?

Comment: So all the routers (or more accurately, access points) have the same SSID and are not on the same network or working properly? You have a network problem, not an Android problem, your network is not functioning properly... if the APwithout internet access should have it, correct it or remove it from the equation, if it should not have Internet access then it should not have the same SSID. Android isn't capable of manually selecting a specific AP from a group with the same SSID.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

I use an app called wifi connection manager. Do you have physical access to the router? If so, you  could goto "advanced" in the wifi menu then use WPS to connect to the router by pressing the WPS button on the router.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple. For this you need an app that shows signal of different router ( or channels). I recommend you [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer) app which is free on play store. 
I have tried this app in my hostel. You can see every detail of every router near by you even of same SSID. There you can choose which router to connect.

Answer (score -1):

Drag the notification bar and long press the wifi icon. Now you can see the list of available wifi. Choose which one you need to connect and then type the password(if exists)

Comment: I'm not sure whether that's an option. If I read the question correctly, all those routers share the same SSID (and hence appear with a single entry) – otherwise asking for "how to select another *router*" doesn't seem to make much sense, as it should be pretty obvious.